# OData with EF Core / ASP.NET Core - Good or Bad?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've read a lot about OData with EF Core / ASP.NET Core.
It seems to me that everybody has an opinion on this and It's gotten a bit confusing, so at the risk of sounding dumb, I have a few questions:

Please note:

! I'm NOT talking about the classic ASP.NET 4.6 or 4.7 with EF6 !

! I'm talking about ASP.NET Core with EF Core !

1. Considering building API - Is there stuff that EF Core alone couldn't handle as well as EF Core with OData?
2. Considering building API - Is it not better to build clean RESTful APIs instead of OData style APIs?
3. Isn't implementing OData stuff sacrificing best practices for convenience?
4. What about long term? Aren't ASP.NET Core + EF Core being built with speed and efficiency in mind and thus won't they be faster and more efficient on their own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will go with [Shawn Wildermuth's advice](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnetcore-implementing-securing-api/discussion) that I found on Pluralsight:

> OData means that queries are on the client so that **versioning OData
>   services becomes risky** and it feels like **MS is moving away from it** so
>   I don't have confidence in the long-term viability of it either.

Answer (score 4):

OData on ASP.NET Core/EF Core works very well. Versioning can be accomplished with microsofts versioning api.
I don't necessarily see MS abandoning this technology. There main api (ms graph) is odata 4 compatible.

Using Odata on top of EF Core is really enjoyable for many use cases. Especially the querying part I like a lot.
For implementing writes/commands I usually fall back to webapi/Mediatr.

Here https://www.jannikbuschke.de/blog/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-odata/ and here https://www.jannikbuschke.de/blog/odata-getting-started/ I wrote some thoughts/guides on this topic.

One downside is tooling and community. There is not a whole lot out there.